# Excel VBA Auto Resize ListView Columns

Tags: vba, excel, listview, resize

I found code in order to resize a ListViews columns based on the the longest string in the items of the column, but I would like to modify it so it also considers the length of the column name as well for resizing. I have several columns where the longest string is the column name itself.

I have been searching all over google to try and figure this out, but I really do not understand the API being used here.

An extension to this question would also be, what is **`LVM_FIRST`** doing here, I could not seem to find anything in my searches.

**Declaration:**

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
"SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const LVM_FIRST = &H1000
```

**Sub:**

```
Public Sub LV_AutoSizeColumn(LV As ListView, Optional Column _
 As ColumnHeader = Nothing)

 Dim C As ColumnHeader
 If Column Is Nothing Then
  For Each C In LV.ColumnHeaders
   SendMessage LV.hWnd, LVM_FIRST + 30, C.Index - 1, -1
  Next
 Else
  SendMessage LV.hWnd, LVM_FIRST + 30, Column.Index - 1, -1
 End If
 LV.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LVM_FIRST + 30` is the [`LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761163(v=vs.85).aspx) message which sets the width of the given column.

The `-1` is `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE` which tells the control to resize based on content.  If you switched to `-2` (`LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER`) the control would resize to the header text.

Set both in your loop, noting which results in a larger ColumnHeaders width then `SendMessage` again with the appropriate `LVSCW_` argument.

Comment: Im still pretty new at this. Could you elaborate on what you mean by set both and note the bigger then sendmessage again. You mean like store the larger value in a variable?

Comment: I was going to paste a demo but it looks like USEHEADER honours longer column vlaues, so try replacing the `SendMessage` you have with `SendMessage LV.hWnd, LVM_FIRST + 30, C.Index - 1, ByVal -2`